# What happens if the Pkunk aren't "absorbed" by the Yehat?

Tags: star-control-2

If you don't stop the Pkunk from flying into Yehat territory, the Pkunk disappear from the map and the Yehat claim they have been "absorbed". I've heard that triggering the Yehat rebellion before this happens avoids this unfortunate event. But in my game, the rebellion was already triggered (I'm pretty sure) when the Pkunk met the Yehat, and they were still "absorbed". I cut it pretty fine - the Pkunk were brushing up against Yehat territory when I triggered the rebellion, so I'm wondering if I missed the window of oppurtunity.

What exactly changes depending on whether you start the rebellion early enough or not?

Comment: I may as well mention for anyone else curious: there doesn't seem to be any dialog in the source code that would fit a "post reunification" scenario, just the usual stuff about "they have been absorbed".

Answer (score 6):

The Pkunk-Yehat conflict can end in two ways. If the Captain presents the Yehat a living Shofixti, the Yehat Rebellion will break out and the Pkunk will be absorbed, seemingly vanishing, only to return in the last moment as an integral part of their combined civilizations.

If the Captain fails to do so, the Pkunk are eradicated by the Yehat.

Sources: [1](http://www.gog.com/forum/star_control/consequences_of_pkunk_arrival_before_or_during_the_yehat_rebellion), [2](http://wiki.uqm.stack.nl/Yehat_Rebellion)

Comment: But the point of the question is that the Yehat are sort of ambiguous, so how exactly can I tell which scenario I'm in? In my game the Yehat said the Pkunk were "absorbed", which sounds like it could be a euphemism for "we killed them, this is the bad scnario". In which scenario do they say that? And what exactly do they say in the other scenario?

Comment: No, you aren't late. If you hear this, you will still be able to incite the revolution by bringing a live Shofixti to them.